# Python pandas extra 0 in numeric values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple code that read csv file. After that I change the names of the columns and print them. I found one weird issue that for some numeric columns its adding extra .0 Here is my code:

```
v_df = pd.read_csv('csvfile', delimiter=;)
v_df = v_df.rename(columns={Order No. : Order_Id})
for index, csv_row in v_df.iterrows():
   print(csv_row.Order_Id)
```

Output is:
149545961155429.0

149632391661184.0

If I remove the empty row (2nd one in the above output) from the csv file, .0 does not appear in the ORDER_ID.

After doing some search, I found that converting this column to string will solve the problem. It does work if I change the first row of the above code to:

v_df = pd.read_csv('csvfile', delimiter=;, dtype={'Order No.' : 'str'})

However, the issue is that the column name 'Order No.' is changing to Order_Id as I am doing the rename so I can not use 'Order No.'. For this reason I tried the following:

v_df[['Order_Id']] = v_df[['Order_Id']].values.astype('str')

But unfortunately it seems that astype is not changing the datatype and .0 is still appearing. My questions are:

1- Why .0 is coming at the first place if there is an empty row in the csv file?
2- Why datatype change is not happening after rename?

My aim is to just get rid of .0, I don't want to change the datatype if .0 can go away using any other method.

Comment: try int instead of str, I think for str type it first goes to float and then the literal number is transformed to str

Comment: Int doesn't work. I tried that. It still shows .0

Comment: do you have the csv or some lines of it so that i can simulate the code? thanks

Comment: The file is:

Transaction Date,Fee Name,Seller SKU,Pre-VAT Amount,VAT in Amount,Post-VAT Amount,WHT Amount,WHT included in Amount,Paid Status,Order No.,Order Item No.,Order Item Status,Comment
13-Oct-22,Commission Fee,WMC00WMCAQ82100001,-31.88,-5.1,-36.98,0,No,Paid,149545961155429,149545961255429,Delivered,
12-Oct-22,Handling Fee,,-130,-19.5,-149.5,0,No,Paid,,,,Handling Fee - Orders delivered 26th September - 02nd October
15-Oct-22,Product Price,WMC00WMCM916000001,260,0,260,0,No,Paid,149632391661184,149632391761184,Delivered,

Comment: Here is the trimmed down version of the code and file:

v_df = pd.read_csv('test_file.csv', delimiter=',') # Read a csv file
v_df.fillna('', inplace=True) # Replace nan values to empty string

v_df = v_df.rename(columns={'Order No.':'Order_Id'})

# Reading csv file and inserting data in the table
for index, csv_row in v_df.iterrows():
   print(csv_row.Order_Id)

-------------

Transaction Date,Order No.,Order Item No.,Order Item Status
13-Oct-22,149545961155429,149545961255429,Delivered
12-Oct-22,,,delivered
15-Oct-22,149632391661184,149632391761184,Delivered

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to emulate your df here, although it has some differences I think it will work for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



v_df = pd.DataFrame([['13-Oct-22','149545961155429.0','149545961255429','Delivered'],
              ['12-Oct-22',None,None,'delivered'],
['15-Oct-22','149632391661184.0','149632391761184','Delivered']], columns=
                  ['Transaction Date','Order_Id','Order Item No.','Order Item Status'])


v_df[['Order_Id']] = v_df[['Order_Id']].fillna(np.nan).values.astype('float').astype('int').astype('str')
```

Try it and let me know

Comment: Hi Karen, Thanks for responding. One thing, you have added the order number with .0 in the dataframe. Actually its not the case. The csv file does not have .0 in the order number, the .0 comes in when I read the file using pandas.

Comment: yes, I was trying to emulate the problem, since I am manually inputing the data it reads it already fine so I purposedly caused an issue which I think has the same root that yours have, does the workaround work in your case as well?

Comment: I ran the code you sent and in the end I printed the dataframe. Below is the output. The Order number coming in the output is difference from what is there in the dataframe:

 Transaction Date     Order_Id   Order Item No. Order Item Status
0        13-Oct-22  -2147483648  149545961255429         Delivered
1        12-Oct-22  -2147483648             None         delivered
2        15-Oct-22  -2147483648  149632391761184         Delivered